# Refering to dynamically selected keys in XML Schemas

Tags: xml, xsd

If I have an XML document that goes something like this:

```
<Choices name="Numbers">
    <Choice>1</Choice>
    <Choice>2</Choice>
    <Choice>3</Choice>
</Choices>
<Choices name="Letters">
    <Choice>A</Choice>
    <Choice>B</Choice>
    <Choice>C</Choice>
</Choices>
<Selected>
    <Selection category="Letters">B</Selection>
</Selected>
```

I would like to describe a constrain in an XSD that makes sure that the selection tags data only refers to choices in the category "Letters". Is this something that is doable? It is fairly easy to do it with keys as long as you are OK with it having any choice in any category as it's data, but I'm stumped on how to limit which categories choices it can refer to.

Comment: What version of XML Schema are you using? Can you use Schematron?

Comment: 1.1 is the version, I do not think we want to use Schematron.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using XSD 1.1 you can use assertions to test it. Example:

```
<xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="Choices" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element ref="Selected"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:assert test="every $selection in Selected/Selection satisfies
               exists(Choices[@name=$selection/@category and exists(Choice[text()=$selection])])"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

My example assumes you can have multiple unrelated *Selection* nodes inside *Select*. You can use *xs:unique* and/or other assertions to test other things (e.g.: *Choices* names are unique, *Selection* categories are unique, every *Choice* has a *selection*, etc)